# How to detect always-on display in swiftui in a Live Activity?

Tags: swiftui, activitykit

According to apple, a Live Activity should be able to detect always on display

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities

> On devices that include an Always-On display, the system dims the
> screen to preserve battery life and renders Live Activities on the
> Lock Screen as if in Dark Mode. Use SwiftUI’s isLuminanceReduced
> environment value to detect reduced luminance on devices with an
> Always-On display and use images that look great for reduced
> luminance.

But it seems to have no effect in live activities when displayed in the lock screen with AOD

```
  @Environment(\.isLuminanceReduced) var isLuminanceReduced
    Image("background1")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(height: 400)
                            .offset(y:-40)
                            .brightness(isLuminanceReduced ? -0.5 : 0)
```

There's also nothing else in the context that seems to be able to tell as well
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/activityviewcontext

Comment: TimelineView, the context can tell you

Comment: @loremipsum can you clarify what you mean? I dont see anything like that in the context https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/activityviewcontext

Answer (score 0):

It isn't explicitly documented but `context.cadence` let you detect  when the updates will happen slower than requested.

> The system might use a cadence that’s slower than the schedule’s update rate. For example, a view on watchOS might remain visible when the user lowers their wrist, but update less frequently, and thus require less detail.

```
TimelineView(.periodic(from: startDate, by: 1.0)) { context in
    AnalogTimerView(
        date: context.date,
        showSeconds: context.cadence <= .seconds)
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchos-apps/updating-watchos-apps-with-timelines

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchos-apps/designing-your-app-for-the-always-on-state

Apple demonstrates its use in [Build a workout app for Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/build_a_workout_app_for_apple_watch)

Comment: sorry I should have clarified in the question, this is inside a live activity